# Whats the best/most used way to format/indent function parameter objects

Tags: javascript, coding-style, code-formatting

I was wondering how StackOverflow crowd prefers to indent their code, and how would you indent/format the code below.

```
  this.router.navigate([
  'search', {
  filters: btoa(JSON.stringify({
      author: uid,
      byLikes: -1,
      requireInteractions: true,
      limit: ContentListComponent.contentPerLoad
  }))}
  ]);
```

I cant really find a good ... nice looking way to make the (), [], {} match.

Comment: Usually one inherits the contents of a block one level more than the line on which the parentheses are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.router.navigate([
     'search', {
         filters: btoa(JSON.stringify({
             author: uid,
             byLikes: -1,
             requireInteractions: true,
             limit: ContentListComponent.contentPerLoad
         }))
     }
 ]);
```

simply indent when a new block begins.

If you are using sublime-text there is a nice package called JsFormat which you can let run over a file and it will automatically correct intent problems (doing also other stuff). Check it out here: https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat

Answer (score 0):

Use [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) and you won't need to worry about how to format code anymore.